# Forked repo not showing as forked on Github, can't find original repo anymore

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-fork

I forked someone's public repo earlier to contribute to it.

Cloned the repo, submitted a PR.

But when I've gone to check the PR in github,  I've noticed that the repo is showing on my account, but there's no mention of it being forked?

When I try to find the original repo on the users profile, using the original url I just get the standard Github 404 page. I cannot see any public repo's anymore on their Github profile.

Apologies, as this is only my second contribution to an open source project, but why would this be?

Shouldn't the repo on my account show that is was forked from the original repo?

Could it be because the owner of the original repo has now changed it to private?

It's showing on my profile almost as if I'm the owner of the original repo.

Comment: Reading the below, I assume they must have changed the repo's visibility?

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility

Comment: Yes it is because the repo has been turned private or was removed. You simply don't have the needed rights / privileges to view the repo. Contact the original user and let them know you have a copy of the repo and would like to contribute.